# Why numpy.dot acts differently from numpy.matmul when a data-frame and an array are passed to multiply?

Tags: arrays, numpy, dataframe, matrix-multiplication

Hi to all the code enthusiasts

Try to be concise: train_features is a Dataframe, say 15435 rows × 56 columns and weights_input_to_hidden is a numpy array, say (56, 8). Why these two codes act so differently?

```
hidden_inputs = np.matmul(train_features, weights_input_to_hidden)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (15435, 8), indices imply (15435, 56)
```

while

```
hidden_inputs = np.dot(train_features, weights_input_to_hidden)
```

produces an (15435, 8) array as expected!

I know how to make np.matmul work by passing dataframe.values but I try to understand the reason. My broader question, I guess would be isn't more safe to always use numpy.dot? Is there a downside to it?

Thanks

Comment: Both `matmul` and `dot` have to convert the dataframes to a numpy arrays.  Even if the underlying call to BLAS functions is the same, it's possible their converversion routes are slightly different.  Did the `matmul` case provide a traceback?  Usually `numpy` functions will to a `np.asanyarray(arg)` to the inputs.  In straighforward pandas cases that probably is the same as `arg.values`.  Can you provide simple dataframes that demonstrate the issue?

Comment: The error message appears to issued by `pandas`, not `numpy`.  `numpy` doesn't know anything about `pandas` indices.  `np.matmul` is now a `ufunc`, and as such may be delegating more responsibility to `pandas`.  This pandas issue may be relevant: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26650

Comment: Here is a simple dataframe: `random_train_features = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))` and for weights: `weights_input_to_hidden = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1, size=(4, 8))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [331]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD')); arr = np.rand
     ...: om.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1, size=(4, 8))                                                     
In [332]: df                                                                                           
Out[332]: 
     A   B   C   D
0   89  32  48  98
1   30  82   4  80
2   33  19  37   5
3   52  54  85  59
...  
14  56  12  20  95
In [333]: arr                                                                                          
Out[333]: 
array([[-1.07529431, -1.81065918,  1.07124769, -1.48496446,  0.30771816,
         0.44839516,  0.59052604,  0.13464351],
       [ 1.02452572,  0.69012042,  0.93467643, -0.76834263,  0.64154991,
         0.8636691 , -0.953216  ,  0.39123113],
       [-1.07415575,  1.24940955, -0.97997359,  0.64934175,  1.65194464,
         0.37485754,  0.61134192,  2.34500983],
       [-0.69994102,  0.56102524,  0.14815698, -0.07709728, -0.27005677,
        -0.15430032,  0.52354464,  0.42093538]])
```

The `dot`:

```
In [334]: np.dot(df,arr)                                                                               
Out[334]: 
array([[-183.07006635,  -24.11268158,   92.73134126, -133.1359306 ,
         100.74429239,   70.4163106 ,  102.70569257,  178.3148074 ],
       [  -8.53962464,   52.14975688,  116.71356194, -111.12344468,
          46.84187465,   73.42812559,  -16.11899202,   79.17512792],
       [ -59.26219127,    2.39381449,   17.59178789,  -39.96217878,
          82.11581512,   44.30498042,   26.61362943,  100.74666767],
       ...
          32.31431554,   28.31277828,   83.59444567,   99.12386781]])
In [335]: _.shape                                                                                      
Out[335]: (15, 8)
```

The matmul with FULL traceback:

```
In [336]: np.matmul(df,arr)                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1653                 blocks = [
-> 1654                     make_block(values=blocks[0], placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))
   1655                 ]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype)
   3046 
-> 3047     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   3048 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    124             raise ValueError(
--> 125                 f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "
    126                 f"placement implies {len(self.mgr_locs)}"

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 8, placement implies 4

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-336-efb905aa1e5d> in <module>
----> 1 np.matmul(df,arr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __array_wrap__(self, result, context)
   1916             return result
   1917         d = self._construct_axes_dict(self._AXIS_ORDERS, copy=False)
-> 1918         return self._constructor(result, **d).__finalize__(self)
   1919 
   1920     # ideally we would define this to avoid the getattr checks, but

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    462                 mgr = init_dict({data.name: data}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    463             else:
--> 464                 mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    465 
    466         # For data is list-like, or Iterable (will consume into list)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in init_ndarray(values, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    208         block_values = [values]
    209 
--> 210     return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
    211 
    212 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1662         blocks = [getattr(b, "values", b) for b in blocks]
   1663         tot_items = sum(b.shape[0] for b in blocks)
-> 1664         construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
   1665 
   1666 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   1692     if block_shape[0] == 0:
   1693         raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
-> 1694     raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
   1695 
   1696 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (15, 8), indices imply (15, 4)
```

As I suspected, `matmul` has delegated some part of the task back to `pandas`, as illustrated in this pandas `issues`:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26650

They say that `pandas` has its own `__matmul__`, so the operator version works:

```
In [337]: df@arr                                                                                       
Out[337]: 
             0           1           2           3           4           5           6           7
0  -183.070066  -24.112682   92.731341 -133.135931  100.744292   70.416311  102.705693  178.314807
1    -8.539625   52.149757  116.713562 -111.123445   46.841875   73.428126  -16.118992   79.175128
2   -59.262191    2.393814   17.591788  -39.962179   82.115815   44.304980   26.613629  100.746668
3  -133.190674   82.412526   31.620913  -68.063345  175.126984   92.713852   62.086887  252.288966
4  -117.745733    8.202933   15.816666  -53.176516  124.940168   59.727122   61.493886  168.665106
....
14 -135.899685  -14.829880   65.681429  -86.715528   32.314316   28.312778   83.594446   99.123868
In [338]: _.shape                                                                                      
Out[338]: (15, 8)
```

This calls: `df.__matmul__(arr)`.  Note that the result is a dataframe, not an array.

In sum, use the operator `@` rather than `np.matmul`.  Or do your own dataframe to array conversion:

```
np.matmul(df.to_numpy(),arr)
```

Some timings:

```
In [343]: timeit np.matmul(df.to_numpy(),arr)                                                          
24.9 µs ± 1.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [344]: timeit np.dot(df,arr)                                                                        
50 µs ± 134 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [345]: timeit df.__matmul__(arr)                                                                    
180 µs ± 390 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [346]: timeit np.dot(df.to_numpy(),arr)                                                             
21.3 µs ± 47.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

If you just interested in an array result, converting the dataframe yourself is a good idea.